# C: realloc() not functioning as expected

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

If I have a variable, `str` that I would like to allocate memory to on the heap, I would use `malloc()` like:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof("Hello"));
```

`malloc()` is returning a `void*` pointer, which is the memory location where my memory is.
So now, I can give it some data

```
str = "Hello";
```

So, the memory location is now full, with 6 bytes. Now, I want to increase its size, to contain the string `"Hello World"`. So, I use `realloc()`. According to `man`,  `void* realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)` will:

```
The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes. 
The contents will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up to the minimum of 
the old and new sizes. If  the  newsize is larger than the old size, the added memory will not 
be initialized.
```

So I assumed that it will return a `void*` to the new, now bigger memory location, which I can now fill with my new string, so going on the same logic to `malloc()`:

```
str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof("Hello World"));
```

But, this is where the problem is. This will cause:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400664 ***
```

And in valgrind

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
```

This suggests that there is something wrong with the pointer, `str`. So I decided to remove:

```
str = "Hello";
```

And it compiles fine, with the following code:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof("Hello"));
str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof("Hello World"));
```

I am aware of the fact that pointer to `realloc()` must come from `malloc()`, but simply assigning data to it shouldn't cause `realloc()` to fail, which suggects that I am doing something completly wrong.

**So, what am I doing wrong?**

And here is the code that fails:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof("Hello"));
str = "Hello";
str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof("Hello World"));
// str = "Hello World"; - this is what I would to be able to do.
```

**Note:** This code is something I have stripped down from a much larger program, just 
to demonstrate the problem I am having, so I have removed checks etc.
Also, I am very new to C, so hence the really simple problem (sorry?), but after hours of work and research, I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong - It seems to work fine for everyone else!.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`; it's not necessary, and in some cases it can mask errors.

Comment: @wildplasser: Ok, let's clean up the obsolete comments (including this one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C you *cannot* copy around blocks of memory as you tried to do:

```
str = "Hello";
```

That is ***not*** a valid string copy; instead, it leaves your malloc'd memory unaccounted for ("leaked"), and changes the pointer 'str' to point to a hard-coded string.

Further, because str is now a pointer to a hard-coded, static string, you cannot realloc it.  It was never malloc'd to begin with!

To fix this, you want to change: `str = "Hello";` to this:

```
strcpy(str, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Hello";
```

is the problem. You allocated a buffer and made `str` point to it. You then need to copy into that buffer. Like this:

```
strcpy(str, "Hello");
```

But instead you changed the value of the pointer.

When you call `realloc`, you must pass to `realloc`, a pointer that was created by an earlier call to `malloc`, `realloc` or similar. But you did not do that. Because you modified `str`.

Answer (score 1):

> `malloc()` is returning a `void*` pointer, which is the memory location where my memory is.

So far so good

> So now, I can give it some data

```
str = "Hello";
```

You are right on being able to give that memory some data, but you are wrong on a way of doing it: you cannot reassign the pointer to a string literal - this would create a memory leak. Instead, you should *copy* the data into the memory block, like this:

```
strcpy(str, "Hello");
```

If you do an assignment instead of a copy, the pointer no longer points to something returned by `malloc`, making it illegal to pass that pointer to `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

This instruction:

```
str = "Hello";
```

doesn't allocate any memory in the heap.

Comment: No, it's not on the stack. String literals are statically allocated (i.e., the allocated memory exists for the entire execution of the program).

Comment: @KeithThompson You are right, I said wrong. I wanted to say that they are in the code segment, is this correct?

Comment: What's a "code segment"? The C language standard only says that the array corresponding to a string literal has static storage duration; it doesn't mention segments. It may well be in the code segment for many implementations. What matters is that it's not on the heap (though the standard doesn't use the term "heap" either).

Comment: Ok, it's now correct, but it's incomplete since it doesn't actually explain what the problem is. The fact that string literals are not on the heap is just one of several things going on in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

`char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof("Hello"));`

You are allocating memory dynamically to the `str`. **Good**. You are `cast`-ing the return value of `malloc()`, **Not good**.

`str = "Hello";`

You are trying to put the address of the `static` string `"Hello"` in `str`. **Why?** This is actually **overwriting** the memory address allocated by `malloc()`. What `str` contains is not a dynamically allocated pointer right now. It's a *static* address, which is not eligible for `realloc()`/ `free()` . Also, you are taking yourself into a zone of *memory leak*. What I think is you need `strcpy()` instead.

Comment: [No, you almost certainly *don't* want `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: No, the assignment doesn't overwrite the memory allocated by `malloc`. `str = "Hello"` is a pointer assignment that causes the pointer `str` to point to a static array containing `"Hello"`. The memory allocated by `malloc` is not overwritten. Rather, the only pointer to it is lost, resulting in a memory leak. See [belenky's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20938614/827263).

Comment: @KeithThompson oops. Bad choice of words I guess. What I meant to say is the memory `address` allocated by `malloc()` is overwritten, as in, the `value` of `str` itself (returned by `malloc()`) is overwritten. I had already mentioned about the leak. Guess this clears the confusion. And thanks once again for the comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid the reallocation of memory issue use the function strdup :

```
char *str = strdup("hello");
str = strdup("hello word");
```

**strdup** returns a pointer to the storage space containing the copied string. If it cannot reserve storage strdup returns NULL.